# Can I change the font of the text-mode console?

Tags: console, tty, fonts

I have a Unix-like OS installed without a windowing environment; *i.e.*, just a text-mode console and no GUI.

Is it possible to change the font used by the console?

To be clear, I am *not* talking about the terminal emulator that comes with a desktop environment like KDE or GNOME.

Comment: Sure: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Console_fonts

Comment: @Blender - hello from 2019! That resource has apparently moved here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console#Fonts

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you use the Linux console, the best way I found is:

in

`/etc/default/console-setup`

put, for example

```
CHARMAP="UTF-8"
CODESET="Lat7"
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="28x14"
```

Another way is to use [`setfont`](http://www.kbd-project.org/manpages/man8/setfont.8.html) from the [`kbd`](http://www.kbd-project.org/) package:

`setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat7-Terminus28x14.psf`

This works for my Debian; it may be different for you.

In Debian, you can also run `dpkg-reconfigure -plow console-setup` to be prompted for the various console settings and pick them from menus.

**Edit** - I put together a small [page](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/cols/www/index.html) how to setup the font **colors**. The section that is relevant for this post has the header "the Linux VTs" (= ttys, or "console").

Comment: Font sizes listed by `dpkg-configure console-setup` are: 6x12, 8x14, 8x16, 10x20, 11x22, 12x24, 14x28, and 16x32.

Comment: I had to reboot for this to take effect

Comment: I used `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` solution, and after i made my selections of font options, it modified `/etc/default/console-setup` and ran `update-initramfs` (i suppose with `-u` option).  However, your answer does not mention running `update-initramfs`.  Is it necessary?

Comment: @mt025 you may use the command `setupcon` to apply the changes.  It is part of the `console-setup` package.

Comment: On some distros (at least on Arch), the fonts will be in `/usr/share/kbd/consolefonts`. I will add a separate answer to highlight the `setfont` solution.

Comment: All the font sizes listed in `dpkg-configure console-setup` were smaller than I'd like for my 4K monitor. I want the font to be 5 times bigger!

Answer (score 16):

`/etc/default/console-setup` et al. have been superseded on systemd operating systems, although you will find that some operating systems such as Debian try to maintain the older configuration system.

The way to do this on a systemd operating system is to edit the font settings in the `/etc/vconsole.conf` file.  These settings are applied by the `systemd-vconsole-setup` service, which is essentially a glorified way of running [`setfont`](http://kbd-project.org/manpages/man8/setfont.8.html) and [`loadkeys`](http://kbd-project.org/manpages/man1/loadkeys.1.html) before the login services are brought up.

So you would have `FONT=Uni2-Terminus28x14` in that file, for example.

Note that the service program allows kernel command-line options such as `vconsole.font` to override `/etc/vconsole.conf` contents.  If you are mucking around with GRUB kernel command-line options, bear this in mind.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al.. [`vconsole.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/vconsole.conf.html).  systemd manual pages.  FreeDesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al.. [`systemd-vconsole-setup`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-vconsole-setup.service.html).  systemd manual pages.  FreeDesktop.org.
- [Setting console font in vconsole.conf does not work (systemd)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57085/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326804/5132

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is `systemd`-specific and changes the default for all users.

Comment: `FONT=Uni2-Terminus28x14` does not seems to work because there is no such font in my Arch-based system. Actually I don't care about the font face itself, but all I want is making the text bigger, because it is too small to read. Isn't there any way just to double or triple the console text size, without changing the font face?

Answer (score 11):

Using Ubuntu 16.04 (probably works in all supported versions), I edited `~/.bashrc` and just before terminal splash at end of file, inserted the `setfont` command:

```
# Set font when running in console
/bin/setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat2-Terminus32x16.psf.gz    

# Splash Calendar and time
now

# ASCII Linux distribution display
screenfetch
```

Now when selected <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and get nice big fonts.

This is the largest font available and you can see a complete list with `ls` command:

```
$ ls /usr/share/consolefonts
Arabic-Fixed15.psf.gz             Lat15-Terminus20x10.psf.gz
Arabic-Fixed16.psf.gz             Lat15-Terminus22x11.psf.gz
Arabic-VGA14.psf.gz               Lat15-Terminus24x12.psf.gz
    (... SNIP ...)
Lat15-Terminus14.psf.gz           Vietnamese-Fixed16.psf.gz
Lat15-Terminus16.psf.gz           Vietnamese-Fixed18.psf.gz
```

### Sample screen

This is a facsimile, not a true screen capture from console where screen is wider by 20% and background is black:

[image: Sample console fonts]

Prior to changes I couldn't read the screen on HDPI monitor.

Comment: That's nothing to do with the question. You're running a terminal in a gui.

Comment: @RichieHH The `~/.bashrc` is processed when you open a terminal too. I just can't do a screen shot of a terminal session because there is no GUI running.

Comment: A user having some trouble with the instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409347/error-when-i-go-the-the-root-sudo-s

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use nearly *any* X-compatible font you should have a look at David Herrman's work on [`kmscon`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/kmscon/). The name slightly belies the project, actually, as Kernel Mode Setting is not a requirement for it to work - it also works with with frame-buffer devices - for instance if you are using proprietary AMD or nvidia display drivers. With [`kmscon`](https://github.com/dvdhrm/kmscon) you get multi-seat session management, `xterm` like keyboard and UTF-8 font handling and session control. Changing the font can be done via the `/etc/kmscon/kmscon.conf` or via a command-line option.

Comment: Given the age of this answer this makes sense, but for anyone reading this answer nowadays, there appears to have been **no update to kmscon since 2014**. I can imagine there are lot of security and compability issues with such an unmaintained tool

Comment: Project is not dead, it's just that development happens on different branches nowadays: https://github.com/Aetf/kmscon is the main one, and https://github.com/MacSlow/kmscon has a lot of cool, experimental new features.

Answer (score 6):

`setfont` worked for me. Choose a font; usually they are listed in one of these:

- `/usr/share/consolefonts`
- `/usr/share/kbd/consolefonts`

For example, to use the font `/usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/ter-v32n.psf.gz`, you can enter

```
setfont ter-v32n
```

Answer (score 5):

A dead-simple, if inflexible, solution is to run `setfont -d`, which doubles the size of the current font. Running it twice won't quadruple the size, though (or at least not on my system).

Comment: At first i thought it did not work, because I ran it with `sudo`. I removed `sudo` and then it worked. But this seems to be applied to only the current session. If I log out and re-log in, the font goes back to its original size. How to make it persistent?

Comment: I imagine putting the command in some file that loads when you start the shell -- `~/.inputrc` or `~/.profile`, for instance -- would have that effect.

Comment: `/usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts/` on Fedora

Answer (score -2):

In Linux Mint 18.1 terminal:

1. Right click anywhere in the black space.
2. Choose "profiles", "profile preferences".
3. Put a tic in "custom font" box.
4. Click on the big text sample box next to it.
5. Choose whatever font size and type you want.

The changes will appear immediately.

Comment: I think the question is about [Linux console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console) (`tty1` -- `tty8`).

Comment: You saw the words `without desktop` @Never Too Old To Learn?