# Setting console font in vconsole.conf does not work (systemd)

Tags: arch-linux, console, fonts, systemd

I am trying to set a different default console font for my new Arch Linux installation (using systemd).

I set up my `vconsole.conf` in `/etc` as so:

```
KEYMAP=us
FONT=Lat2-Terminus16
```

I rebooted and saw my newly set console font appear, only for it to reset just before the login prompt.

Things to note:

- running `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-vconsole-setup` manually works fine
- `systemctl status systemd-vconsole-setup.service` tells me that it has loaded and is "active (exited)"
- I have indeed included the `consolefont` hook  in `mkinitcpio.conf`

Answer (score 17):

I spent the better part of tonight solving this same issue, even though it's 2 years later! So to avoid a [DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/) moment for future visitors, here's what solved my issue.

From this [email thread](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2011-June/002562.html):

1. As root, edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-vconsole-setup.service`
2. Change the `After=` and `Before=` lines to:

   ```
   After=sysinit.target
   Before=shutdown.target
   ```
3. Save & Quit
4. Reboot

Your console font should now be correctly applied.

Comment: OMG finally someone figured this one out! I am very glad and allso sad that noone on Archlinux forum has posted this solution...

Comment: Instead of editing, I guess it would be better to override: http://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services

Comment: And 3 years later still the same issue with this. Where do you put After/Before directives? In *Unit* or *Service* groups?

Comment: `systemd-vconsole-setup.service` has changed a bit.

Comment: @71GA please feel free to edit the answer, make a new one, or otherwise make sure this question has the most relevant and correct answer

Comment: Also mentioned in that email thread: try the (boring) `lat0-{08,10,12,14,16}` fonts before giving up entirely. At least on CentOS (7), the Terminus console fonts don't seem to work at all, and this had [stumped Lennart](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2011-June/002618.html), too.

Comment: On Debian 11 this does not work. File `systemd-vconsole-setup.service` is again moved... I hate this... Where can I find it? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your graphics drivers set in the `MODULES` array in `mkinitcpio.conf`? For instance here is mine from my laptop with Intel graphics.

```
MODULES="i915 ahci sd_mod ext4"
```

AMD will need `radeon`, Nvidia will need `nouveau`.

You will also want to be sure that your locale is set properly. Such as `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.conf`.

Relevant wiki pages:

- [mkinitcpio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio.conf)
- [Kernel Mode Setting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Mode_Setting)
- [Locale](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale#Setting_system-wide_locale)

Comment: This is not a good solution.

Comment: For future adventurers, this isn't a great solution because changing the initial ramdisk means you're guaranteed to need to rebuild the ramdisk later when graphics drivers are updated. If you're okay with the occasional (and likely inconvenient) task of using mkinitcpio or dracut to rebuild your ramdisk image... fare thee well, brave soul. Otherwise, figure out the ordering of systemd units that's causing the vconsole configuration to be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian none of the solutions will work. You have to use `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` command to change fonts!

Comment: I can confirm that `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` works fine on Debian 11 (bullseye).

Comment: For me `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow console-setup` worked on Ubuntu 20.04. Does anyone know what `-plow` does? I couldn't find that on the MAN pages.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Arch** 
The only thing that worked for me:

Making a new file / script in: **/etc/systemd/system/"script.service"**

*call it EKS: **fonts.service***

```
[Unit]
Description=fonts

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-vconsole-setup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Making it executable:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 fonts.service
```

Then enabeling the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable fonts.service
```

*alternetive is to edit the /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-vconsole-setup.service. But i find that it breaks things*

Answer (score 1):

Exact same thing happened to me, even after following the wiki word for word. I think it came down to my hybrid graphics. These are the steps I took to get it working.

First, make sure to check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console#Persistent_configuration. I have a Nvidia card, so I also followed their instructions on Early Loading.

However, it turns out I needed to add more modules to `mkinitcpio.conf` than just the Nvidia ones the wiki recommends. I used `lsmod | grep nvidia` to single out my running Nvidia modules. My `video` module is used by `nvidia_modeset`, `msi_wmi`, and `i915`. I added these extra modules to `mkinitcpio` and ran `sudo mkinitcpio -P`. Now my font sticks on reboot!

(BTW -- looking at past comments on this page -- changing the `MODULES` array IS the recommended solution in the wiki.)

Just make sure to add a pacman hook for the appropriate driver so you don't have to run `mkinitcpio` after every Nvidia driver update.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA#pacman_hook

I hope this helps someone!