# How can I configure /etc/kmscon/kmscon.conf to use specific a) font and b) keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, configuration, console, fonts

I recently installed kmscon on my system. Now I want to configure it to use a different keyboard layout (neo2) and, while I am at it, a different font, too. I stumbled across [this question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-terminal) when searching for configuration file examples. But nowhere I could find an example configuration file or instructions how to format the configuration. Can you point me to any additional resource or give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further investigation brought me to [this page](https://www.mankier.com/1/kmscon). Now my config file looks like the following:

```
# config file for kmscon linux console
xkb-layout=de
xkb-variant=neo
font-name=Inconsolata
font-size=10
```

This answers both my questions.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, start with the man page, `man kmscon` in this instance.

Although David Herrmann never got around to what [kmscon bug #71](https://github.com/dvdhrm/kmscon/issues/71) originally asked for, the kmscon manual page provides both an example configuration file and the information that any `kmscon` command-line option is also a `kmscon.conf` setting.