# swapping keys in a virtual terminal

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

Note: I asked this question in superuser about a month ago, but there hasn't been a reply till then, and the question relates to linux, so I'm posting it here.

I want to swap esc and caps_lock keys on my keyboard. `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape` gets the job done but only for X. The keys behave in original way on a virtual console. How can I make them behave in the required way on a vc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`loadkeys`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/loadkeys.1.html).

To swap <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> in the console, run

```
printf 'keycode 1 = Caps_Lock Caps_Lock\nkeycode 58 = Escape Escape\n' | sudo loadkeys -
```

Comment: Is it ok to set the sticky bit on `loadkeys`, so that I can put it in login script. Or shall I make another executable which calls `loadkeys` and set sticky bit on that.

Comment: @Saga: Add `saga ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/swap-esc-tab` to `/etc/sudoers` (use e.g. `EDITOR=nano visudo` to edit the file with `nano`), create root-executable shell script `/usr/local/bin/swap-esc-tab` that runs the command shown in my answer, and finally add `sudo /usr/local/bin/swap-esc-tab` to your login script.

Comment: Note that when I have lots of such scripts, I tend to put the scripts that require root in `/usr/local/admin-bin/`, with simple `exec sudo /usr/local/admin-bin/command "$@"` wrapper bash/dash scripts in `/usr/local/bin/`, and add `nominal-animal ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/admin-bin/*` to  `/etc/sudoers`, so I can run those scripts as a normal user, only acquiring root for those specific scripts.

Comment: Nice setup, I think I'll do the same.

Answer (score 5):

## Debian and `console-setup`

On Debian Linux and Debian FreeBSD, the design is for the X server and the kernel virtual terminals to share one set of configuration information.  The `console-setup` package provides tools and startup scripts that take the keyboard/font configuration of the X server, convert it, and use it to configure the kernel virtual terminals.

Specifically: The `console-setup` service invokes the `setupcon --save` command, which generates scripts in `/etc/console-setup` containing the converted keyboard and font setup instructions, which are run against the kernel virtual terminal devices by udev rules.  The keyboard map is converted from XKB to `loadkeys` format by `ckbcomp`, and the generated script invoked from the udev rule runs `loadkeys`.

So on Debian Linux and Debian FreeBSD you need to ensure that your `XKBMODEL`, `XKBLAYOUT`, `XKBVARIANT`, `XKBOPTIONS` variables are properly set in `/etc/default/keyboard`.  In your case in particular you need to ensure that the `XKBOPTIONS` variable has `caps:swapescape`.  Then you need to ensure that you have the `console-setup` package properly installed.

## systemd Linux

On systemd operating systems, things are somewhat less integrated than on Debian.  There's a configuration file named `/etc/vconsole.conf` and a service named `systemd-vconsole-setup.service` that processes it at system bootstrap (in response to a udev rule announcing the existence of the kernel virtual terminal subsystem).  But this isn't joined up with the X server configuration at all.

The `vconsole.conf` file has a `KEYMAP` setting denoting the keyboard map that is passed to `loadkeys`, which again one does not need to explicitly run oneself.  But *it's left entirely up to you* to create a (customized) keyboard map that swaps <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd> and put it where `loadkeys` can find it.

To get more joined up settings, one has to involve another two services, `systemd-localed` and the Desktop Bus.  One runs, say,

```
localectl set-x11-keymap pl pc105 "" "caps:swapescape"
```

and the locale D-BUS service goes and rewrites `/etc/vconsole.conf` with its best guess as to the *nearest equivalent* map for the kernel virtual terminal.  This nearest equivalent may not be *exactly* equivalent, though, and you may find it just outright ignoring options and suchlike.

Of course, you could always alternatively use Debian's `ckbcomp` by hand to directly convert an XKB keyboard map.  ☺

## Further reading

- https://superuser.com/questions/709616/
- https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard
- [`systemd-vconsole-setup-service`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-vconsole-setup.service.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- [`vconsole.conf`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/vconsole.conf.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Karsten Hilbert (2014-08-29).  *[console-setup w/ systemd forgets font setting](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=759657)*.  #759657.  Debian bug tracker.
- [`localectl`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/localectl.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479720/5132