# Detect terminal font

Tags: debian, terminal, xfce, fonts

I am running Debian live XFCE, and I cannot seem to determine the font used by
the Terminal.

I went to Edit, Preferences, Appearance and it just says "Monospace Regular".

Then I did `cat /etc/default/console-setup` and it just says `FONTFACE="Fixed"`.

Can I somehow get the actual, proper font name, or alternatively the path to the
font file being used?

Comment: What terminal are you using? Why would `/etc/default/console-setup` be relevant? Isn't that about the console (as opposed to the GUI terminal emulators) font?

Comment: It's relevant because the questioner is running Debian.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326804/5132

Comment: @JdeBP ah, thanks I didn't know that.