# Powerline Fonts for zsh in TTY

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, configuration, tty, fonts

I'm using UBUNTU 16.04. 
In graphical terminals like "Terminal" "guake" and "terminator" I am using zsh with Powerline-Fonts.
I looked around a bit but found no proper solution to activate powerline fonts for the TTY as well.
I want to make them alvailable for all users on the system.

Is there a way I haven't seen?

Comment: Because `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` doesn't let you pick any font (probably for stability reasons) I don't think it is easy. You can try running that command however, and see what I mean. I think you can get pretty deep into this and actually do it with some fancy footwork, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-terminal#49823

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been playing around with it but I can't get it to persist: https://superuser.com/questions/1449412/setting-up-powerline-fonts-in-my-text-console-setfont-works-but-setupcon-doesn