# Embedded Linux TTY font change

Tags: linux, tty, embedded, fonts, busybox

I'm using Linux kernel + Busybox on an embedded system with a video console (`fbcon`) on LCD. I'd like to be able to change between compiled-in fonts (e.g. VGA 8x8, MINI4x6) on runtime. I know it's possible to do it before boot via boot parameters (`fbcon=font:VGA8x8`). Busybox has `setfont` utility but it doesn't seem to work with the compiled-in fonts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-terminal

Comment: That question doesn't concern the compiled-in fonts. It suggests using setfont which I already ruled out in my question.