# Setting the most basic text console video mode on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, console, x86

I have a HP ThinClient computer (t5740) for a special use. Since it has VGA output, I can only connect it via VGA-to-HDMI converter to a monitor (it does not have VGA input).

When it boots the BIOS screens in the low resolution and big default fonts display works all right. `grub` screen occasionally also gets displayed.

However, once kernel starts booting and switches video output to some different mode and to smaller fonts, the image disappears and monitor switches into a sleep mode after a few seconds.

Since the BIOS screens display fine, I want to switch kernel's/`grub`'s video mode (resolution, refresh rate, font size etc) to exactly this kind of configuration. I have tried all kinds of ways like `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`, setting various video modes in `grub.cfg` and whatever I could find on the web. Nothing worked.

How can I make `grub`/kernel use exactly the most basic video mode that the box displays during BIOS operations?

OS: Debian Buster (10), i386 arch (that's the CPU).

Comment: Take a look here, see if it helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-the-text-mode-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. In `/etc/default/grub` set following variables:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768@60
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Run `update-grub` afterwards.

`nomodeset` alone did not solve the problem. I had to specifically set `GRUB_GFXMODE` and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX` like this.

It is instructive to use `fbset` to check *actual* video mode set. For some reason after boot it was *always* `1920x1440` no matter what I set previously with `GRUB_GFXMODE` alone. Apparently that mode is outside resolutions  supported by my VGA2HDMI converter.

It *may* have had something to do with Intel graphics. This computer has Intel graphics chipset (Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller) and I've seen people around the web doing some Intel-related kernel module blacklisting to get video working properly.