# Debian terminal not displaying correct Unicode half-block characters

Tags: debian, terminal, unicode, text

I have a program that prints Unicode half-block characters (U+2580, U+2584), but on Debian 10 terminals (just the fullscreen terminal, no X), it's printing diamonds instead of half-blocks.

The two images below are the output of a Python program...

```
import sys
print(f"character encoding: {sys.stdout.encoding}")
print(chr(0x2580)) # upper half block
print(chr(0x2584)) # lower half block
print(chr(0x2588)) # full block
```

...followed by the output of `locale`.

| macOS / SSH (correct) | Debian (diamonds) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Also here are the contents of */etc/default/console-setup*:

```
admin@flipdisc:~$ cat /etc/default/console-setup 
# CONFIGURATION FILE FOR SETUPCON

# Consult the console-setup(5) manual page.

ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"

CHARMAP="UTF-8"

CODESET="Lat15"
FONTFACE="Fixed"
FONTSIZE="8x16"

VIDEOMODE=
```

I've noticed that:

- The macOS Terminal application prints the half-blocks correctly.
- When I SSH to the Debian machine in the macOS Terminal, it also prints the half-blocks correctly.
- The Debian terminal prints diamonds.
- I have a few other Debian machines and they also all print diamonds.
- The Debian terminal *does* print full blocks correctly, for some reason.

The `locale` output identifies `en_US.UTF-8` for both machines, and I'm not sure what else to check.

So my questions are:

- Why is the Debian terminal printing diamonds instead of the correct half-block characters?
- How do I make it print the correct characters?

Comment: just curious, did you try to use a different font?

Comment: Could you add the contents of `/etc/default/console-setup`? (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-the-text-mode-console)

Comment: @Panki I've added the contents of that file.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I did not, because I don't know how (I didn't even know you could do that). I'll research how to change fonts and if I can make something work I'll post back here.

Comment: @JasonC See the question I linked, one of the answers mentions that.